# Developer Documentation in Xcode 3.2 - a step back or is my installation screwed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I've upgraded to Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2 but now I don't get the usual Developer Documentation any more. When I click on 'Developer Documentation' all I get is the Xcode QuickStart guide. No search field, no browsing the library, nothing. Only if I cmd+opt+shift (?) double click on e.g. NSString the API documentation of NSString comes up. But again, no search field, I can't browse the library etc. 
I can't imagine that this is the normal behavior. I've already tried to deinstall Xcode and reinstall it again - same result.
Any idea of what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Home" button in the documentation window's toolbar (is your toolbar hidden, perhaps?) will list the documentation sets you have installed. You'll want to install them from the "Documentation" page of Xcode's preferences window, it's the last one.

Yes, this is slightly annoying that you have to take the extra step, and it's very nonobvious where the extra step is.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a toolbar. Will try to figure out how to enable the toolbar again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In 10.6, Xcode relies entirely on the web to retrieve developer docs rather than having a local copy. Have a look at [this blog post](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-09-02/the-other-way-to-install-the-mac-reference-library); it tells how to grab the documentation files off of Apple's servers and make them available locally on your machine within Xcode.